# Django throws NOT NULL IntegrityError when trying to create record with @property method

Tags: python, django

So I'm relatively new to Django and I'm making a flashcard app with SQLite3 as my development database. I have two models: One for decks of cards, and one for the cards themselves which have a foreignkey relation to decks. In order to know how many cards are in a deck I created a method with the @property decorator that runs count() on card_set and returns the value.

Here's the deck model from models.py:

```
class Deck(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=256)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    dateCreated = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    dateModified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Deck, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def numCards(self):
        return self.card_set.count()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.title
```

The relevant function in views.py (still under construction):

```
@login_required
def create_deck(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = deckForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            userID = request.user.id
            user = User.objects.get(pk=userID)
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            desc = form.cleaned_data['description']
            deck = Deck(author=user, title=title, description=desc)
            deck.save()
            for tag in form.cleaned_data['tags']:
                deck.tags.add(tag)
            deck.save()
            return HttpResponse('success')
    form = deckForm()
    return render(request, 'notecards/create_deck.html', {'form': form})
```

In my unittests the numCards field works as expected (ie it returns the correct amount of cards in the deck) and decks can be created without cards. But when I try to create a deck in my actual site, Django returns an IntegrityError saying "NOT NULL constraint failed: notecards_deck.numCards" ("notecards" is the name of the app). Here's the relevant test that passes (using FactoryBoy):

```
class TestNotecardViews(TestCase):

    def test_deck_model_numCards(self):
        deck = DeckFactory()
        for i in range(0, 10):
            CardFactory(deck=deck)
        self.assertEqual(10, deck.numCards)

    def test_create_deck(self):
        a = self.client.login(username='auser', password='apass')
        self.assertTrue(a)
        user = User.objects.get(username='auser')

        resp = self.client.post(reverse('create_deck'),
                                {'title': 'Test Deck',
                                 'description': 'The description',
                                 'tags': 'test, test2'})
        self.assertContains(resp, 'success', 1)
        deck = Deck.objects.get(title='Test Deck')
        self.assertEqual(deck.author, user)
        self.assertEqual(deck.description, 'The description')
        self.assertEqual(deck.slug, 'test-deck')
        self.assertCountEqual(deck.tags.names(), ['test', 'test2'])
```

What's going on? Why is Django/SQLite complaining that my numCards "field" is null?

EDIT: Here's the full traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/notecards/create_deck/

Django Version: 1.8.4
Python Version: 3.5.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'taggit',
 'notecards')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Users\murrarc1\Documents\coding\notecardproject\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\murrarc1\Documents\coding\notecardproject\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\murrarc1\Documents\coding\notecardproject\notecardproject\notecards\views.py" in create_deck
  115.             deck.save()
File "C:\Users\murrarc1\Documents\coding\notecardproject\notecardproject\notecards\models.py" in save
  21.         super(Deck, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\murrarc1\Documents\coding\notecardproject\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  734.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "C:\Users\murrarc1\Documents\coding\notecardproject\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  762.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "C:\Users\murrarc1\Documents\coding\notecardproject\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  846.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "C:\Users\murrarc1\Documents\coding\notecardproject\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  885.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "C:\Users\murrarc1\Documents\coding\notecardproject\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  127.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\murrarc1\Documents\coding\notecardproject\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  920.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "C:\Users\murrarc1\Documents\coding\notecardproject\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  974.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\murrarc1\Documents\coding\notecardproject\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\murrarc1\Documents\coding\notecardproject\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\murrarc1\Documents\coding\notecardproject\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  97.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "C:\Users\murrarc1\Documents\coding\notecardproject\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py" in reraise
  658.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Users\murrarc1\Documents\coding\notecardproject\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\murrarc1\Documents\coding\notecardproject\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  318.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /notecards/create_deck/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: notecards_deck.numCards
```

Comment: You have to show us where the code failed, a full stacktrace might also be useful.

Comment: Did you previously define `numCards` as a field, e.g. `numCards = models.IntegerField()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your actual database structure. You've propably created previously `numCards` field in your model and migrated it into database. When removing it from model, it wasn't removed from database. Test will pass because it is running on it's own database.

If column in database exists, create migration to get rid of it (or if you're using your models without migrations, just remove that column by hand) or if you have already that migration, run it using `./manage.py migrate` command.

Comment: Yes, I had originally had numCards as an integerField in Deck. Deleting the test database and re-migrating solved the issue.